# Performance of rendering shadows in Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, shadow

I am working on a minecraft project using Three.js, and I've encountered a performance issue when rendering shadows.

Here is the demo: http://johnhckuo.github.io/Minecraft/

As you can see the FPS drops below 30 and it continues dropping if you stay longer on this page.

I think it's kind of weird because this scale of shadow rendering should be easy for GPU right?

Comment: Have you tested this without the shadows, to be sure that's the problem? It looks like you're creating new meshes and materials on every frame, which would be a more likely cause.

Comment: This question is link only, the repro code is included as a link only. The link is now rotten and the question makes no sense any more.

Comment: @Suma link updated :)

Comment: Glad to hear that. However the question should contain the necessary code in its body, not as a linked project. If the code is too large for the question, it should be reduced. If you cannot be bothered to that, it means the question is unlikely to help anyone else but you and I suggest it should be closed and deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Don said, You are creating new meshes and materials in the render loop.
Specifically how the sky is generated.
The real culprit can be seen via Chrome devtools, which seems to be that when creating the new material with a map (canvas generated every frame), this new map/texture is then uploaded to the GPU (screenshot attached).
Thing to do to  fix your problems may be to:

- Don't create new meshes every frame.
- Don't create new materials every frame.
- Don't create a new canvas for the material every frame, or maybe do this color manipulation within a shader.

Devtools screenshot:
[image]

EDIT:
Take a look at [this sky shader](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_shaders_sky.html)